# Read RDB files with binaryreader

Tags: c#

I am Trying to read an `.RDB File` which is a file containing tables

I tried this

```
var fs = new FileStream(@"db_banword2.rdb", FileMode.Open);
var len = (int)fs.Length;
var bits = new byte[len];
fs.Read(bits, 0, len);
// Dump 16 bytes per line
for (int ix = 0; ix < len; ix += 16)
{
    var cnt = Math.Min(16, len - ix);
    var line = new byte[cnt];
    Array.Copy(bits, ix, line, 0, cnt);
    // Write address + hex + ascii
    //MessageBox.Show("{0:X6}  " +  ix);
    //MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(line));
    //Console.Write("  ");
    // Convert non-ascii characters to .
    for (int jx = 0; jx < cnt; ++jx)
        if (line[jx] < 0x20 || line[jx] > 0x7f) line[jx] = (byte)'.';
    listBox1.Items.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(line));
}
```

and I got the values but with many dots 
as shown in this picture

[image]

but I need the values to be as shown in this picture

[image]

without dots

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: All you're doing is dumping the file, everything of it. What the other tool does is that it scans for strings (even with several encoding options). Like the Unix-tool `strings` you need to loop through the binary content of that file and detect the start of an ASCII / UTF-8 / Unicode string. (you already check that in your code as I can see). Ergo, in your code, if a non-ASCII-printable appears don't print it all, then if an ASCII-printable character appears, print it all until there's a non-printable char.

Comment: there is obviously some format to the file that you are not accounting for.  what is a rdb file and what does the layout look like?

Comment: the rdb file is used to store sql table for a game called rappelz